# A characterisation of the cyclic subfactors by the existence of a cyclic vector?

Tags: operator-algebras, quantum-groups, von-neumann-algebras, hopf-algebras

A [**cyclic subfactor**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133050/the-cyclic-subfactors-theory-a-quantum-arithmetic) is a subfactor admitting a distributive intermediate subfactors lattice.

Let's start with the finite index irreducible depth 2 subfactors, i.e. the class of subfactors of the form $(R^{\mathbb{A}} \subset R) $ with $R$ the hyperfinite II$_{1}$ factor and $\mathbb{A}$ a finite dimensional Kac algebra (Hopf C*-algebra).

By a theorem ([here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123697932286) p 54) of Izumi-Longo-Popa, there is a (Galois) correspondence between the intermediate subfactors of $(R^{\mathbb{A}} \subset R) $ and the left coideal subalgebra of $\mathbb{A}$.

So $(R^{\mathbb{A}} \subset R) $ is a **cyclic subfactor** if and only if the left coideal subalgebras lattice of $\mathbb{A}$ is distributive. Let call such a Kac algebra, a **cyclic Kac algebra**.

Now, Izumi-Longo-Popa (p52) gives the following characterization of the left coideal subalgebras :

> **Definition**. A unital von Neumann subalgebra $\mathbb{B}$ of a
> Kac algebra $\mathbb{A}$ is called a left (right) coideal von Neumann
> subalgebra if and only if $\Delta(\mathbb{B})\subset \mathbb{A}\otimes \mathbb{B}$
> (respectively $\Delta(\mathbb{B})\subset \mathbb{B}\otimes \mathbb{A}$) holds.
>
> Let $Corep(\mathbb{A})$ be the category of finite dimensional unitary
> corepresentations of $\mathbb{A}$.
>
> **Proposition**. Let $\mathbb{A}$ be a compact Kac algebra. Then
> there exists one-to-one  correspondence between the following two
> sets.

- The sets of left coideal von Neumann subalgebras of

> $\mathbb{A}$.

- The set of systems of Hilbert subspaces $K_i
   \subset H_i$, $i \in Corep(\mathbb{A})$ satisfying  the following:

> $$K_i \oplus K_j \subset K_{i \oplus j}, \quad i,
>  j \in Corep(\mathbb{A}).$$ $$K_i \otimes K_j \subset K_{i
>  \otimes j}, \quad i, j \in Corep(\mathbb{A}).$$
> $$\overline{K_i}=K_{\overline i}, \quad i \in Corep(\mathbb{A}).$$

**Definition** :  We call the system $(K_{i})$ above, a ILP system (for Izumi-Longo-Popa).

A subfactor is [maximal](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133651/is-there-a-maximal-finite-depth-infinite-index-irreducible-subfactor?lq=1) if it has no non-trivial intermediate subfactor. Then we call a Kac algebra "maximal" if it has no non-trivial left coideal subalgebra (obviously maximal $\Rightarrow$ cyclic).

**Definition** :  Let $j \in Corep(\mathbb{A})$, then $v \in H_{j}$ is called **fusion-cyclic** if the ILP system it generates is the whole system, i.e., if $(K_{i})$ is a ILP system with $v \in K_{j}$, then $\forall i$, $K_{i} = H_{i}$.

**Observation** : $\mathbb{A}$ is a **maximal Kac algebra** if and only if $$\forall  i \text{ non-trivial and } \forall  v \in H_{i}, v \ne 0 \text{, then $v$ is fusion-cyclic.}$$

> **Question** : Is it true that $\mathbb{A}$ is a **cyclic Kac algebra** if and only if $$\exists  i  \text{ (irr.?) and } \exists  v
>  \in H_{i} \text{ such that $v$ is fusion-cyclic ?}$$

**Remark**: Oystein Ore [1938](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-4/issue-2/Structures-and-group-theory-II/10.1215/S0012-7094-38-00419-3.short) proved, on one page, that a finite group is cyclic iff its subgroups lattice is distributive. I hope its proof adaptable in the Kac algebra framework, for answering the question above.

---

**Generalization to subfactors**:  Every finite depth, finite index, irreducible subfactor, is of the form $R^{\mathbb{I}} \subset R$, with $\mathbb{I} \subset \mathbb{A}$, a left coideal subalgebra of a finite dimensional *weak* Kac algebra $\mathbb{A}$ (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001020)).

The intermediate subfactors of $R^{\mathbb{I}} \subset R$ are given by the left coideal subalgebras $\mathbb{J} \subset \mathbb{I} \subset \mathbb{A}$.

**Remark**: I don't know if the proposition above is true in the *weak* case, I suppose it is.

Let $(L_i)$ be the ILP system of the left coideal subalgebra $\mathbb{I} \subset \mathbb{A}$.

**Definition** :  Let $j \in Corep(\mathbb{A})$, then $v \in L_{j}$ is called $\mathbb{I}$-**fusion-cyclic** if the ILP system it generates is the system $(L_i)$, i.e., if $(K_{i})$ is a ILP system with $v \in K_{j}$, then $\forall i$, $K_{i} = L_{i}$.

**Observation** : $R^{\mathbb{I}} \subset R$ is a **maximal subfactor** if and only if $$\forall  i \text{ non-trivial and } \forall  v \in L_{i}, v \ne 0 \text{, then $v$ is $\mathbb{I}$-fusion-cyclic.}$$

> **Question** : Is it true that $R^{\mathbb{I}} \subset R$ is a **cyclic subfactor** if and only if $$\exists  i  \text{ (irr.?) and } \exists  v
>  \in L_{i} \text{ such that $v$ is $\mathbb{I}$-fusion-cyclic ?}$$

**Remark** : A subfactor is also given by a **fusion category** and an **algebra object**. Then the lattice of intermediate subfactors is given by the lattice of subalgebras objects of the algebra object.
Is there a way to translate the question above in the language of the fusion categories ?

Comment: I suppose it's your choice where to post but isn't this question much more suitable for MO?